# Elucidate an obfuscated javascript code block

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to elucidate an obfuscated javascript code block???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these -

http://elfz.laacz.lv/beautify/

http://www.brianfolts.com/un/ - Works only in FF

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how it's obfuscated. You likely won't be able to get the original code, but with first pretty-printing and then hand-analyzing the code (if it's just minimized/compressed) you'll get pretty far.

If it's obfuscated code that's `eval()`ed, you'll need to go through additional hoops to get to the code that is passed to `eval()` (or just monkey-patch `eval` yourself to do something like print the parameters).